# How to use PHP in the header of a drupal view?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a drupal view, which displays a content type filtered by a url argmuent (e.g. category). Now i'd like to add a link in top of my view, which allows my users to add a new node. In the add form the argument field should be prepopulated with the value from the filter.

I think to archive this, i have to install the prepopulate module and add some php-code to the header section of my view, which generates the link.

Any suggestions how to manage this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to add php code to get the arguments passed to views in the views header section, do the following:

1. Make sure that the PHP filter is turned on; this is a module that can be enabled
2. In the header section use the following code:

`$view = views_get_current_view();

    // [0] is first arg, [1] is second etc.

    $argumentOutput = $view-> args[0];`

Remember to have the input format set to PHP code. This will get you the argument passed to views.

Comment: There are better ways to insert PHP code into Drupal resources without turning on the PHP filter, since there are some downsides to using it.  See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to override the template for the view and insert the code/markup there. Check out the `Theming infomation` inside the view to find out what to call your template.